# If $a\sqrt{a} - 7\sqrt{a} = 2\sqrt{5}$ what is the value of $a-\sqrt{5a}$?

Tags: radicals

Actually this is a little urgent. 
While I was studying for the exam I encountered with this question. Neither my friends nor I could find the solution. It really seems easy though.
Is there a short way or formula that I don't know?

Comment: What is $a$? (Real, rational, integer?)

Comment: I think $a$ is positive real number. It should suffit.

Comment: It isn't given in the question. @SiXUlm

Comment: I guess the solution is 2 because this is what i found. Below you can see the way to the solution. @TakahiroWaki

Answer (score 5):

If $t = \sqrt{a}$, your equation says $t^3 - 7 t - 2 \sqrt{5} = 0$.
It's annoying to have that square root in the equation, so let $t = \sqrt{5} u$, and then it becomes $5 u^3 - 7 u - 2 = 0$.  This factors as $(u+1)(5 u^2 - 5 u - 2)$, from which you can get the solutions.  Caution: you probably don't want negative values of $t$.

Comment: Thanks! This really helped me. :)) but i'm not sure that they expect this solution from us. If there is a quicker way, i'd really want to learn that, too.

Comment: This is as quick as it can get. If there is no rational solution of $A u^3+B u+C=0$ with non-zero integers $A,B,C$ then it gets long. But there is a quick way to find rational roots, if any, when $A.B,C$ are integers..